# Create new gmail contacts with a url request?

Tags: url, contacts

I'm developing a new member sign up page with Google App Engine, I want to create a new contact each time a new user fills out his info and clicks a submit button, I looked into Google contacts api, but it doesn't seem to work for me, I've included all the jar files, but it still complained that something is missing, see my previous questions for details at :

[How can google app engine create new contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389126/how-can-google-app-engine-create-new-contacts)
and
[Google App add contact error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398633/google-app-add-contact-error)

So I wonder if there is a simpler way to add new contacts through a URL request, something like this :

```
https://google.contacts.com/new_contact?App_Name=myapp&Id=myId&password=mypwd&name=newUserName&email=newuser@email.com...
```

Does something like that exist ? If it does, it will avoid a lot of coding and confusion. Just add a new contact each time a request is made and authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite that simple, but it's possible.

See http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Creating

Basically, your app would need to authenticate against your account using OAuth, the form the body of the create request, and then POST it to `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full` to add the contact.

The docs are quite thorough - I recommend a complete readthrough.